# Python Selenium execute multiple chrome browser with each profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium in Python, I want to run a separate Chrome browser in multiple profiles.

While executing the code below, I got the following error.

How can I fix it?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

USER_DATA_DIR = r'C:\custom_chrome'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    option = Options()
    option.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={USER_DATA_DIR}")
    option.add_argument(f"profile-directory=Profile 1")
    option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('chromedriver.exe'), options=option)

    option2 = Options()
    option2.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={USER_DATA_DIR}")
    option2.add_argument(f"profile-directory=Profile 2")
    option2.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('chromedriver.exe'), options=option)

    driver.get('google.com')
    driver2.get('google.com')

    print('aaaa')
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

TRY TO:

Multiprocessing, create 2 files for the chrome driver and try each one.

Create chrome as a subprocess and attach it to debugging mode with option.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"127.0.0.1:{port}"). Note that I used different ports for each of these.

version:
selenium    4.8.2

chrome 115.0.5790.110

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?